# como utilizar o cursor no mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, back-end

quando vou fazer a requisição pra pegar os valores do debts e credits da esse erro:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "name": "MongoError",
      "message": "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument",
      "ok": 0,
      "errmsg": "The 'cursor' option is required, except for aggregate with the explain argument",
      "code": 9,
      "codeName": "FailedToParse"
    }
  ]
}
```

ja vi algumas maneiras de utilizar, mas não funciono nenhuma, pelo que li a partir da versão 3.6 do mongo é preciso setar o curso, minha versão é `"mongoose": "^4.7.0"` e a do professor também, na videoaula ele consegue fazer a requisição sem usar o cursor, ele disponibilizo o código funcionando, no entanto o erro persiste aqui

o código

```
BillingCycle.route('summary', (req, res, next) => {
    BillingCycle.aggregate({
        $project: {credit: {$sum: "$credits.value"}, debt: {$sum:
        "$debts.value"}}
        }, {
        $group: {_id: null, credit: {$sum: "$credit"}, debt: {$sum: "$debt"}}
        }, {
        $project: {_id: 0, credit: 1, debt: 1}
        }, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            res.status(500).json({errors: [error]})
        } else {
        res.json(result[0] || { credit: 0, debt: 0 })
        }
    })
})
```

se puder exatamente colocar onde deveria ficar o cursor nesse código agradeceria muito, obrigado desde já.

Comment: Eu aconselho vc a trabalhar na ultima versao do mongoose. Caso isso nao seja possivel esse erro de cursor pode ser resolvido na versao "mongoose": "4.13.7"

Answer (score 1):

Olá é possível resolver este problema atualizando o mongoose, testei com esta versão e funcionou: npm install mongoose@4.12.2

Answer (score -1):

Olá, Estou Fazendo o mesmo exercício e recebi o mesmo erro. Percebi que no meu banco estava cadastrado value no tipo String. Acredito que seja este o erro que esteja acontecendo. Até porque na mensagem de erros temos o retorno de "codeName": "FailedToParse".